Unable to Build/Archive Project from Xcode ( Module not found )
I've been debugging my flutter app on iOS simulator and it has been working fine, but when I try to build/archive project from Xcode, it fails, resulting in this error.
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m Module 'connectivity_plus' not found

The solutions that I have tried;

Removing and recreating the iOS directory.
Uninstalling and reinstalling the cocoapods.


ⓘ I'm able to build the ipa using flutter build ipa command.


My flutter app depends on internet_connection_checker_plus, which depends on the connectivity_plus plugin.


How are you opening the file? Open ios/Runner.xcworkspace. You can also try to change platform in podfile. Set platform :ios, '13.0'

I always open the workspace, and I have already set the platform to 13.0, and it matches my minimum deployment target.

Module not found happens a lot to me as well. Mostly it works by running flutter clean and deleting .symlinks, Pods, Podfile.lock and  pubspec.lock and rerunning it. Sometimes I have to move it to a new project. You can also try Product -> Clean build folder in xcode.

I have tried creating a new project, but that didn't fix the issue. Cleaned the build folder many times. I haven't tried deleting pubspec.lock though.

Any solution with this one? @ASADHAMEED

Building the ipa from the terminal worked for me, but the permanent solution would be to recreate the ios folder. Make sure to create a backup and do not loose the IOS settings.
